# Req.params is undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I implemented my own custom router which routes request coming into my server.

```
const routesHandler = ({ router }: RouterDep): Router => {
 // Authorization middleware
  router.use(DeserializeUser);

  // Admin routes
  router.use('/admin/', adminRouter);


  return router;
};
```

the router here is that of `const router = express.Router()`

This is how i use the router in my entry file;

```
app.use('/api/v1', routesHandler({ router }));
```

where app is `const app = express()`

The adminRouter:

```
function makeAdminAPIRouter({
     adminAuthController,
     electionController,
  }: Controllers) {
  return function route(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
// TODO: Refactor routing logic
if (req.path.startsWith('/auth')) {
  adminAuthController(req, res, next);
}
if (req.path.startsWith('/elections')) {
  console.log(req);

  electionController(req, res, next);
}
}}

export const adminRouter = makeAdminAPIRouter({
 adminAuthController,
 electionController,
})
```

and i have a `PUT` route `/admin/elections/update/:id`, which matches `/admin/`, but the id is returning undefined. i can access the req.body and req.query, but the req.params is returning undefined.

This is where i check the request and call the appopriate handler

```
function makeElectionEndpointHandler({ electionService }: Dep) {
return async function handle(httpRequest: THttpRequest) {
const httpData: THttpData = {
  body: httpRequest.body,
  params: httpRequest.params,
  query: httpRequest.query,
};

switch (httpRequest.method) {
  case 'POST':
    return bindRequestResponse(await 
  electionService.Create(httpData));
  case 'PUT':
    {
      const routes: Record<string, any> = {
        '/elections/update/:id': electionService.Update,
        // To add more PUT routes here
      };
      const matchingRoute = matchRoutes(routes, httpRequest.path);
      if (matchingRoute) {
        return bindRequestResponse(await routes[matchingRoute] 
      (httpData));
      }
      ThrowError(`Cannot ${httpRequest.method} to 
    ${httpRequest.path}`);
    }
    break;
  default:
    break;
}};
```

Is there something wrong with my implementation?

Comment: Without knowing anything else an issue in a path handler we can’t see configured in a way we don’t know will be tricky.

Comment: @DaveNewton I added more context

Answer (score 0):

When you create a custom router in Express using `express.Router()`, parameters won't be passed to it. This means that you can access parameter values only in your main entry file and not in the custom router.

To make parameters accessible in the custom router, you need to instruct Express to pass these parameters using `{ mergeParams: true }` when creating the router, like this:

```js
// customer-router.js
const customRouter = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
```

This allows parameters to be passed from the main entry file to the custom router, enabling access to them within the router.